# Is there a method for adding points to a user from outside of Joomla?

Tags: jomsocial

I have built a web app that couples with a community built with JomSocial and I want to be able to award points to users within the community when they do things in the app. I already have ties to Joomla built in to my app, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how points work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes there is a way. http://documentation.jomsocial.com/wiki/User_Points_System

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @oooooo's recomendation I used this code to build a method for adding points.

> Calling the UserPoints API in Your Code If you want to give points to
>   a user, you will need to call the API by inserting the codes where you
>   want them.
>
> include_once
>   JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_community/libraries/core.php';
>   include_once
>   JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_community/libraries/userpoints.php';
>   CuserPoints::assignPoint('your.action.string');
>
> The your.action.string is the rule registered in database with how
>   many points awarded to the current logged-in user. You will need to
>   give a unique action string to your components such as
>   'com_name.profile.upload.avatar'. In some situations, where you want
>   to give points to another user instead of the current logged-in user,
>   you can call the API's in the following manner:
>
> ```
> include_once JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_community/libraries/core.php';
> include_once JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_community/libraries/userpoints.php';
> CuserPoints::assignPoint('your.action.string', 62);
> ```
>
> By giving the userId (62) as the second parameter, the API will give
>   points to the specified user.

Here's the method I used. Hope it helps someone.

```
include_once JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_community/libraries/core.php';
include_once JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_community/libraries/userpoints.php';
function addPoints($user_id, $action_string = null){
    if($function_name == null){ $action_string = DEFAULT_ACTION_STRING; }
         CuserPoints::assignPoint('your.action.string', $user_id);
    }
}
```